# WPF: при смене изображения, освобождать память предыдущей картинки

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите найти решение

Профилировать не удается, занятая под изображение память показывает как unmanaged - и больше ничего не могу из этого вытянуть(использую ANTS). Ниже приведен код в котором сборщик затирает только каждое третье загруженное изображение, т.е. 2 последних постоянно висят памяти. Это очень критично при больших изображениях.

```
private void map()
        {            
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();            
            byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);//сюда подставляются image
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer); 
            BitmapImage bitmap33 = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap33.BeginInit();           
            bitmap33.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap33.EndInit();
            bitmap33.Freeze();
            img.Source = bitmap33; // img это Image лежащая на холсте 
        }
```

Comment: А у кого ссылки на эту самую unmanaged memory?

Comment: Ссылки на bitmap33 и img.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, _из_ bitmap33 и img? А кто держит этот самый bitmap33 в памяти? Посмотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Коли используете конструкцию
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
то после вызовы WaitForPendingFinalizers нужно еще раз вызывать Collect.

Comment: Ничего из вышеизложенного не помогло. Я как и прежде имею 1 лишнюю картинку в памяти. Из PerfView ничего толком получить не смог (возможно из-за неумения с ним работать). В VMMap отчетливо видно эту память в куче - но кроме видения ничего получить не смог. Вероятно придется фрагментировать изображения чтобы не было краха из-за иногда отсутвующей свободной памяти одним фрагментом. (очень не хотелось бы по ряду причин)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена !

```
UpdateLayout();
GC.Collect();
```

Особая благодарность в решении проблемы Tykac'у (Ижевск. Россия)!